# Formula that relates to sheet name in current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Say there is

1. `wbA.sheet1` and `wbA.sheet2` (workbook A with sheet1 and sheet2)
2. `wbB.sheet1` and `wbB.sheet2` (workbook B with sheet1 and sheet2)

In `wbA.sheet1`, cell `A1` has formula `=Sheet2!B1`.
When you copy this cell `A1` to `wbB.sheet1`, it will relate to `B1` from `wbA.sheet2`.

However, is it possible to change the formula (perhaps with VBA) so that cell `A1` relates to the sheet `"Sheet2"` **in workbook it is currently located**?

That means no matter in which workbook cell `A1` is copied, it searches for sheet `"Sheet2"` in **this** workbook and takes `B1` from it. And does not give `REF!` error.

**Some more details on my case:**

In `wbA.sheet1` formula of cell `A1` calculates daily salary of a worker. It is a product of:

- previous cell (where you input number of hours) and
- **hourly rate coefficient**

The latest is a value in `wbA.sheet2`. You can consider `sheet2` in any `wb` to be a master list of coefficients. However, different workbooks have different coefficients in `sheet2`. Therefore, when I copy cell `A1`, to any other workbook, I would like to have it adjusted to hourly rates in current workbook, and not drag the rates from the initial workbook.

Comment: is this a one-time thing or a dynamic thing? (i.e. you need to change these references once, or you need them to keep changing on the fly?) If the former, then you can just use a Find and Replace through the GUI to remove the part of the reference that links to the difference workbook. If the latter, then something like INDIRECT() function would work, but is not recommended (performance overhead, and text is a static link). Can you describe your use case as perhaps you are approaching something from a slightly unorthodox angle?

Comment: You need to use something like this `[Workbook_Name]SheetName!Cell`. If the sheet has a space in its name, it should be surrounded like this `'Sheet Name'` and you can also include the full path of the workbook where you put the workbook's name! ;)

Comment: @R3uK that does the opposite of what the OP wants, I think. It would always refer to a particular workbook whereas OP wants it to always be relative

Comment: @Cor_Blimey : my bad! As pasteSpecial formulas doesn't work for that, have you tried to transfer `Cells(1,1).Formula` as a string?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I added details to the post

Comment: fun fact, defined names can be used in each (e.g. name Sheet2 cell1 something like `_coefficient1`) then a formula will optionally be pointed to the destination name, so if the 2nd workbook has a name called the same thing, any formulas copied across can use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround could be to use VBA to copy the exact formula of the range.

You could give this a hotkey for convenience. Select the cells you want to copy then run the macro. It will prompt you to select where you want to copy it to.

```
Sub CopyExactFormula()
    Dim sRng As Range, dRng As Range
    Set sRng = Selection.Areas(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dRng = Application.InputBox("Select destination output range (Top left cell)", "Output range", , , , , , 8)
    If dRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set dRng = dRng.Parent.Range(dRng.Cells(1, 1), dRng.Cells(sRng.Rows.Count, sRng.Columns.Count))
    dRng.Formula = sRng.Formula
End Sub
```

An alternative workaround is to use defined names in your formulas for the coefficients. They will change to the defined names in the new workbook, subject to an irritating messagebox prompt that has no "Yes to All" option!